# react native paper Appbar shows extra row or top offset

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper

Good Morning, folks,

This:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Appbar } from 'react-native-paper';

function StatusBarWLT({page, isOnline, navigate}) {
  return (
    <Appbar.Header
    mode="center-aligned"
    style={styles.statusBar}>
      <Appbar.BackAction onPress={() => navigate('home')} />
      <Appbar.Content title={page.title} />
    </Appbar.Header>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  statusBar: {
    backgroundColor: '#f0e',
  }
})
export default StatusBarWLT;
```

Results in this for me:
[Emulator Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baEBx.png)

Where is the extra space on top of <- Home comming from?
Seen this before?
Any Idea?

Node 16
React-Native 0.68.2
react-native-paper 4.12.1
Android API level 30

Comment: I'm sorry this isn't a helpful comment, but this is exactly why I dislike UI frameworks.

Comment: A pad on the shoulder might not be helpful, but makes me feel a bit better :-) 
And yeah, agree...